# Which phrase is correct? (passive voice)

Tags: passive-voice

I am studying passive voice now, which phrase is correct? may be both?

1. We were shown a very strange picture.
2. A very strange picture was shown to us.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are both correct.

Passive voice is generally used to maintain an emphasis on a certain aspect of a story. If the story is focused on *our experiences* then you would probably use #1. If the story is focused on events that *we* just happened to be witnessing, then #2 might be preferable.

Comment: Additionally, in neither case does it matter *who* is doing the showing, which is why passive voice is used in the first place.